# В чём основные различия между OpenGL 3.x и OpenGL 4.x?

Tags: opengl

В чём основные различия между OpenGL 3.x и OpenGL 4.x?
Есть ли смысл изучать старый OpenGL 3, если есть новый. Что они из себя представляют?

Comment: Я бы сказал, четвертый GL - это третий, дополненный разными фичами. Для новичка разницы быть почти не должно. И вообще, то, что он старый - это не плохо. Если новые фичи не нужны, то имеет смысл использовать именно третий, потому что четвертый поддерживается не везде.